# Missing required field: member

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

```
{ errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'required',
       message: 'Missing required field: member' } ],
  code: 400,
  message: 'Missing required field: member' }
```

I get this error when I run the following request:

```
var request = client.admin.members.insert({
    groupKey: "some_group@example.com"
  , email: "me@example.com"
});
```

I was authenticated successfully (I received the access token and so on) but when I execute the request above it callbacks that error.

What `member` field am I supposed to add?

It works fine in [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/directory/admin/directory_v1/directory.members.insert) using `groupKey` and `email` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`email` is part of the form data. The form data must be passed as object in the second argument:

```
// create the group insert request
var request = client.admin.members.insert({
    groupKey: "some_group@example.com"
}, {
    email: "me@example.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert for `admin.members.insert` indicates that it requires a `groupKey` parameter, but that the body (which the node.js library handles as a separate object) should contain a `members` object containing the `role` property. See the API Explorer a the bottom of that page as well.

Comment: *which the node.js library handles as a separate object* - can you update my example to work with the module? What's the name of the object?