# Receiving 400 error, additional fields are required, but I'm including the required field in my data field

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to work with a healthcare API and getting the below error:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": {
        "error": "Additional fields are required.",
        "missingfields": [
            "insurancepackageid"
        ]
    }
}
```

However, I am including this field within my requests data field. I've tried adding it to both json and data

```
ins_headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
          ,'accept': 'application/json'
          ,'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }

ins_data = {"insurancepackageid": int(gci.get_ins_package_id(cust_id))
            ,"insurancepolicyholderfirstname": str(firstname)
            ,"insurancepolicyholderlastname": str(lastname)
            ,"insurancepolicyholdersex": str(sex)
            ,"insurancepolicyholderdob": str(dob)
            ,"caseinjurydate": str('1/1/2020')
            ,"realtedtoautoaccident":True
            ,"relationshiptoinsuredid":1
            }

resp_old = requests.post(ins_url_old,headers=ins_headers,data=ins_data,verify=False)
```

I'm sorry that I have to be relatively vague since I'm worried about HIPAA, but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on what else I should try.

I've tried

```
resp_old = requests.post(ins_url_old,headers=ins_headers,data=ins_data,verify=False)
```

and

```
resp_old = requests.post(ins_url_old,headers=ins_headers,json=ins_data,verify=False)
```

I've also tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473492/insert-member-code-400-message-missing-required-field-member) but it didn't get me anywhere either.

but I get the same error with both. Is there any other way I should write the dict/json to make sure the fields are getting passed correctly?

Comment: Try *json=ins_data* instead of *data=ins_data*

Answer (score 0):

It seems the website requires JSON payload, but you're passing it as form data.

Change this line

```
resp_old = requests.post(ins_url_old,headers=ins_headers,data=ins_data,verify=False)
```

to

```
resp_old = requests.post(ins_url_old,headers=ins_headers,json=ins_data,verify=False)
```

It should work.

EDIT:
Updated final_code to:

```
import json
import requests

ins_data = {
    "insurancepackageid": int(gci.get_ins_package_id(cust_id)),
    "insurancepolicyholderfirstname": str(firstname),
    "insurancepolicyholderlastname": str(lastname),
    "insurancepolicyholdersex": str(sex),
    "insurancepolicyholderdob": str(dob),
    "caseinjurydate": '1/1/2020',
    "realtedtoautoaccident":True,
    "relationshiptoinsuredid":1
}


ins_headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': str(len(json.dumps(ins_data)))
}

resp_old = requests.post(ins_url_old, headers=ins_headers, json=ins_data, verify=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, Zero. I have tried both ways but get the same response in either case.

Comment: Have you tried adding `content-length` header?

Comment: I have not, I only have the content-type and accept set. I'll look into content-length!

Comment: I've tried adding content-length and am still getting the same error
`ins_headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
          ,'accept': 'application/json'
          ,'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          ,'Content-Length': str(10000)
         }
`

Comment: @SnoweWhite, random `Content-Length` doesn't work, you have pass the exact length as payload that you're passing, please check my updated code.

Comment: thank you for the correction. I've updated my code to yours but I'm still receiving the same error :(

Comment: At this point, I think fiddling with the request on Postman would be the best option.